# Get the string before substring using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

here is my string that i am using

```
   SET  @str = 025-121-3453
```

i want to get part of string before expression and after expression using sql

suppose exression is this

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING(String, 
 LEN(LEFT(String, CHARINDEX ('121', String))) + 1, LEN(String) 
- LEN(LEFT(String,
 CHARINDEX ('121', String))) - LEN(RIGHT(String, LEN(String) -

   CHARINDEX ('121', String))) - 1) FROM StringPatternData WHERE String =  '025-121-3453';
```

**output**

in 1 query out put will be '025-'  & in another '-3453'

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Try to explain what you want to do.

Comment: very clear now string before specific text

Comment: What part of "(212) 485-1057" do you want? The part between "(212)" and "1057"? Thus: "485" is what you want?

Comment: I suppose this is a phone number in Istanbul, do you want the phone number without area code?

Comment: NOW CHECK BUT I NEED 2 QUERIES TO GET STRING BEFORE AND AFTER '121'

Comment: @AbdullahNehir  BEFORE AND AFTER 485 IN YOUR QUERY

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: in 1 query out put will be '025-'  & in another '-3453'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with using some built in functions:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = '025-121-3453'

SELECT  LEFT(@str, CHARINDEX('121', @str) - 1) ,
        RIGHT(@str, CHARINDEX('121', REVERSE(@str)) - 1)
```

Note that you will have to provide reversed pattern in second part of the query. I.e. if you are splitting by `123`, second pattern should be `321`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun here is another way you could do this.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100) = '025-121-3453'

select PARSENAME(replace(@str, '-', '.'), 3)
    , PARSENAME(replace(@str, '-', '.'), 1)
```

Comment: no fun needed i have other string too

Comment: What does that mean?